# Method for executing methods with any signature

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, method-signature

Is there any possibility to implement a method which to take as parameters a method name and the set of arguments for the method call, to execute the method and return the return value obtained from the method execution?

This method should be used for calling methods with any number and types of parameters, and any return type.

I know that this can be made using reflection but I am interested if there exist a different approach for this, that would have a smaller effect on the performance than using reflection.

**Later edit:**
I need to implement a method like this because I have a class with many different methods with different method signatures, but the wast majority of them are of the same format:

```
{    
  //code block 1
}
using (SomeObject obj = InitializeObject(){
   ...
   //some operations
   ...
}
{
   //code block 2
}
```

were *code block 1* and *code block 2* are identical, and only the part in the *using* block is different.
I would like to use only one method that would contain the common blocks of code and to call different methods for the parts that differ from one method to another. 
I tried using reflection but it slows down the application in a visible manner so I would not use it.

Comment: Reflection *is* the way of doing things when you only know the name of the method... have you tried this and found it to be too slow?

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Yes, I did tried using reflection, but it significantly slowed down my app.

Comment: you should provide some more data about the nature of the app, depending on which you might be able to go with e.g. generics, expressions etc. or design the system adequately. Given your too general question, the only possibility is the reflection as JonSkeet said

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but if you get the method name as string -> .net reflection is the way to go.

Comment: I have more than the method name, the methods which should be executed are in my code also. I am trying to keep the common behavior from a big number of methods in one single method which would call the parts with are different which would be keped in smaller methods.

Answer (score 1):

Not got time to research the details, but using System.Reflection in combination with Delegate.DynamicInvoke might get you somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage latest DLR capabilities in .NET 4.0

Have a look at [impromptuinterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding) project and its late binding features.

Specifically `InvokeMember` and `InvokeMemberAction` methods. Those are 2x to 4x faster than reflection.

Comment: Thank you, for the suggestion but I would like to use something "embedded" in .NET Framework

Comment: I see, in that case you have to stick with reflection or implement the impromptu functionality subset yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

```
public static string ExecMethodByName
    (string typeName, string methodName, string stringParam)
{
    Type t = Type.GetType(typeName);

    String s = (String)t.InvokeMember(
                    methodName,
                    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | 
                        BindingFlags.Static,
                    null,
                    null,
                    new Object[] { stringParam });

    return s;
}
```